# Find the number with the most digits in an array

Tags: javascript

Here we are. Stuck.

I've decided to create a function that finds the element with the most digits.  If two of them have the same length, return the first one. Common sense tells us that it might be the highest number. Here is the code snippet:

```js
function findLongest(array) {
  var biggestNum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] > biggestNum) {
      biggestNum = array[i];
    }
  }
  return biggestNum;
}

findLongest([111,1111,5555,10000,1,90000]); //returns 90000 instead of 10000.
```

However, I can't meet the second condition (if length of two is the same, return the first one).

Any idea?

Comment: *"Common sense tells us that it might be the highest number"* - but the *first* one *isn't* necessarily the highest number. So why not actually check *the number of digits*, which is the thing you care about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *digit-length* comparing, cast the items into `string` and use `length` of them.

```js
function findLongest(array) {
  var biggestNum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  
    if(array[i].toString().length > biggestNum.toString().length) {
      biggestNum = array[i];
    }
    
  }
  
  return biggestNum;
}

console.log(findLongest([111, 1111, 5555, 10000, 1, 90000]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the integer value of the logarithm of 10 of the value for checking, because you get the count of digits (minus 1) for comapiring.

```js
function findLongest(array) {
    var biggestNum = array[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Math.floor(Math.log10(array[i]) || 0) > Math.floor(Math.log10(biggestNum) || 0)) {
            biggestNum = array[i];
        }
    }
    return biggestNum;
}

console.log(findLongest([111, 1111, 5555, 10000, 1, 90000, 0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The second condition negates the first every time. The "highest number" right?

If you want the highest number why not sort and pop the last element as the returned value?

`array[array.sort(function(a,b){return b - a}).length - 1]`

Iteration of `array` is unnecessary